# Cannot use match on SQLite FTS5 virtual table: unable to use function MATCH in the requested context

Tags: sqlite

A simple test fails when trying to work with FTS5 in SQLite 3.13.0. What am I doing wrong?

```sql
SQLite version 3.13.0 2016-05-18 10:57:30
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE testfts USING FTS5(test);
INSERT INTO testfts VALUES("some test string");
SELECT * FROM testfts WHERE test MATCH 'test';
Error: unable to use function MATCH in the requested context
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM testfts WHERE testfts MATCH 'test';
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM testfts WHERE testfts MATCH 'test:test';
```

The first one will search all columns of the table `testfts` for the string `test`. The second one will restrict the search only to the column `test` (that's what the `test:` prefix in the query string does). The two are equivalent here since there is only one column.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much. It appears I didn't understand the true nature of FTS virtual tables.

Comment: @redneb What if I had total 3 rows and would like to match ORing just two rows?

Comment: You have 3 options: (1) use a boolean expression inside the fts query, e.g. `testfts MATCH 'col1:test OR col2:test'`, (2) mark the third column as `UNINDEXED` (look at the [manual](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html) for more details), (3) move the third column to a different table.

Comment: I have a table with two col of id, content. If I query like : [q = 'SELECT id, content FROM table1 WHERE content MATCH 'university' ORDER BY bm25(content) DESC;']  it doesn't work!!
But if I query for all columns, it works!
any idea?

Comment: @Reihan_amn Please read my answer more carefully. The `WHERE` clause must *always* reference the table, not the column, i.e. in your case `WHERE table1 MATCH '...'`. If you need to match a specific column, you have to reference it from inside the query, as per my second example in the answer above.